# why am I not getting the properties of my generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

What I currently have, is a table, which is used in different components, which will have fixed sets of rows for targeting (QA automation), depending on where it is used.

I'm trying to make a generic of those rows for the table, but the code completion isn't working as intended. What am I missing?

```
class Base {
    protected myRoot : string
    constructor (root : string) {
        this.myRoot = root;
    }
    get base () {
        return "base getter"
    }
}
class FixedRows1 extends Base {
    get id1 () {
        return "id1"
    }
}
class FixedRows2 extends Base {
    get id2 () {
        return "id2"
    }
}
class FixedTable <T extends typeof Base> extends Base {
    private fixedRows : T
    constructor (inRoot : string, inFinalLayer : T) {
        super(inRoot)
        this.fixedRows = inFinalLayer
    }
    get rows () {
        return new this.fixedRows(this.myRoot)
    }
}

const layer = new FixedTable("root", FixedRows1);
layer.rows.base // <---- looking to be able to code complete `.example1`, but currently, only code completes `.base`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tends to eagerly evaluate property accesses or function calls on unresolved generic types; that means when you write `new this.fixedRows(this.myRoot)`, it widens `this.fixedRows` to its constraint of `typeof Base`, and thus returns `Base`.  That's not *wrong*, but it doesn't have enough information for your purposes.  If you want to change this, you'll probably need to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `rows()` returns something else:

```
get rows() {
  return new this.fixedRows(this.myRoot) as InstanceType<T>
}
```

Here I'm using [the `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) to represent the type of the instance constructed by a constructor of type `T`.

Now it should behave the way you want:

```
const layer = new FixedTable("root", FixedRows1);
layer.rows.id1 // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=32&ssc=23&pln=31&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoa0AOAnA9gC4LDEAm0AtgJ4BK+RAXNBIbgJYB2A5hlsPk6tcAV1L5cACgJMWbLtwCUKPlmiEAFuwgA6GvSLQAvNBmEA3KoC+q7gkLQARoknK0mNbnsjcnaACJnCCQ7QmJcf2sMG3RQSBgAMXYADwQyegB3CABGaARk4k4yGHhglQ9Q6HYybNdytVNvXwDq7MiPGJi4qGgk1PT8LIAmPIKEIpLEeuhK6qG69wavQh8-fzn2rE6MbsSUtIAVMEcQBAAeA9HC4vVqbAR8ADM4RAA+K-Gb0qRFnA4ANzAxGgj32AyyzAOqgEQjYYkIEkkXAMhGYwgUABoqpwkpwwCAADJgagIXCQtyqLAQET3KTIhiERSU9RaXSg-qZGAmLi4-FEkm4KIVeymQYQBbM5araCcBAZFnaHTstKcySaRX6BnKSDQACSsLAnGACAOd3OB1eQpiO0ErGg4AFxhlct6YKOJwQkn8Zn8WL6KrF2UUlnQDtJOgIWR0rWgAHpY9B8ABrYlAA)